# Is there a way to send batches of Azure stream analytics data to a python ML pipeline?

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, azure-stream-analytics

I would like to do some machine learning tasks on data as it comes in through stream analytics from event hub. However, much of my data processing pipeline and prediction service is in python. Is there a way to send time chunked data into the python script for processing?

The Azure ML studio function does not suit my need because it appears to work on single rows of data, and the aggregation functions available in Stream Analytics don't seem to work for this data.

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Answer (score 0):

With the recently rolled out integration with Azure functions, you might be able to do that. Try that route.

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function) describes creating an azure function. You will have to create a Http trigger and choose python as the language. There are also templates for several languages.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514057/stream-analytics-egress-to-azure-functions) also has additional details about function.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience,you could put your data into `Azure Storage`.Then configure the `Import Data component` in Azure ML and connect `Execute Python Script` as input data.

[image]

Or you could use [Azure Storage Python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage) to query data in your `Execute Python Script` directly.

However,the two methods mentioned above could only process part of the data at one time, so they should be used only at the `experimental stage`.

If you need to continue processing data, I suggest you use the `web service` component.

[image]

You could put logical code of querying data and processing result into `web service`.Please refer to this [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/publish-a-machine-learning-web-service) to deploy your `web service`.

Hope it helps you.